# Pegar tamanho de um textarea que foi adicionado dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Eu crio uma caixa modal que possui um textarea, ao clicar no botão enviar preciso saber quantos caracteres existem no textarea. O tentar usar o JQuery pra encotrar esse tamanho não me retornado nada. Como posso resolver esse problema?

Comment: Como você criou o textarea? Como já tentou fazer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Desde que você consiga capturar este elemento, não há nenhum problema em contar quantos caracteres tem o TextArea.

É só usar o método `val()` que retorna uma string com todo o texto inserido e depois usar a propriedade `length`.

```js
$('#click-me').on('click', function(){
  var qtd = $('#txtArea').val().length;
  console.log(qtd);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="txtArea"></textarea> <br>
<button id="click-me">Clique</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Isso deve funcionar pra você:

```
$('#textarea_1').val().length
```

Coloquei em um fiddle um código que cria um textarea dinamicamente, e pega o tamanho do valor dele:

https://jsfiddle.net/mtmkheLv/